# unity v2018.2.8f1, C#, weaponSwitching via Instantiating them as a gameObject not syncing, uNet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, synchronization, unity3d-unet

I am making a multiplayer FPS and currently trying to get the weaponSwitching synced.
My problem is:
If I instantiate a new weapon it only shows on the local client.
I do have a equip and deEqip animation, which seem to perfectly sync. The only issue is that the weapon wont change so the animations work and get called, but only on the basic weapon which wont change for the NonLocalClients.

I did not want to spam my code in here, so I pasted it on hastebin:
https://hastebin.com/suhogoyoya.cs

This script is not getting disabled on other clients, but seems to work perfectly on the local clients, whthout any errors and interfierence.

Components I have added to my WeaponPrefabs:
NetworkAnimator, NetworkIdentity(localPlayerAuthority), NetworkTransform

Recap:
1) Animations, basic weapon, movement, shooting, muzzleflashes all synced perfectly
2) The onLocalClient Instantiated weapon wont show up on the other connected clients, which means
when one player in the game switches weapons only he can see his newly equipped weapon.
The other players just see the switching animation and equip-animation for the same weapon, which was equipped from the beguinning.
3) I do want to instantiate the weapon, since I want to implement weaponPickups etc.
4) I have tried all possible combinations of NetworkServer.Spawn(), [Command] etc and searched for 3 days now and can not seem to find a solution so any help would be nice

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
Network.Instantiate(playerPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
```

more info about network prefabs here...
[unity doc reference - netwrok instantiation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Instantiate.html)